# Joining two tables by date ranges

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift

I have two tables I am looking to join by their dates:

table 1:  **reference**

```
| date           |
| -------------- |
| 2018-01-01     |
| 2018-01-02     |
| 2018-01-03     |
| 2018-01-04     |
| 2018-01-05     |
| 2018-01-06     |
| 2018-01-07     |
| 2018-01-08     |
| 2018-01-09     |
| 2018-01-10     |
```

table 2: **events**

```
| id | date       |
| -- | ---------- |
| aa | 2018-01-03 |
| bb | 2018-01-05 |
| cc | 2018-01-08 |
```

I am looking to join the two by their date fields to achieve the following results:

```
| id | reference date | event date |
| -- | -------------- | ---------- |
| aa | 2018-01-03     | 2018-01-03 |
| aa | 2018-01-04     | 2018-01-03 |
| bb | 2018-01-05     | 2018-01-05 |
| bb | 2018-01-06     | 2018-01-05 |
| bb | 2018-01-07     | 2018-01-05 |
| cc | 2018-01-08     | 2018-01-08 |
| cc | 2018-01-09     | 2018-01-08 |
| cc | 2018-01-10     | 2018-01-08 |
```

i.e for each event id, the reference date starts at the earliest event date for that id and ends when the next id kicks in. ( I hope i explained it well).

the code below works if I only have one event with one date. but with multiple events and start dates, it falls apart.

```
select
  events.id,
  reference.date,
  events.date
from events 
join reference on
  reference.date >= events.date
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: using redshift  hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to window functions and CTEs you can simply use `LEAD`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, date, LEAD(date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS end_date
    FROM events
)
SELECT cte.id, reference.date AS reference_date, cte.date AS event_date
FROM cte
INNER JOIN reference ON reference.date >= cte.date
    AND (reference.date < cte.end_date OR cte.end_date IS NULL)
```

Comment: Hi Salman - i have access to window functions and CTEs with redshift but I am getting the error message "Default parameter not be supported for window function lead"

Comment: I removed NULL and it seems to work on SQL Server. LEAD should return NULL for last row (makes sense).

Comment: yes - also tried that and it worked! excelllent! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select r.*,
       (select e.id
        from events e
        where e.date <= r.date
        order by e.date desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as event_date,
       (select e.date
        from events e
        where e.date <= r.date
        order by e.date desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as event_date
from reference e;
```

Note that this uses ANSI-standard syntax.  The syntax for returning a single row could vary by database.

Many databases also support lateral joins and/or `cross apply` which simplifies the subqueries.

Comment: Gordon - this seems to be working but pulls in the first two dates in the reference table . I'd like to date to start on the first date of the event table. Also i see the correlated sub query allows only one item. what if i had several other fields from the events table I wanted to pull in ?

Comment: Gordon - thanks for this. Going with Salmans solution above - seems simpler. Much appreciated.